# JQuery Accordion with content shown before click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

So this is kind of confusing but I want to use a JQuery accordion to show content below some images, it's a pricing sort of thing. I'll just load the images so you guys can see what I'm doing, but I'm not sure how to make the "Click for Details" show underneath the image, then when it's clicked it loads the accordion content and changes to say "Close"? Help please! :(

[Open Content](http://postimg.org/image/mue6tww7t/)

[Closed Content](http://postimg.org/image/h2jh3zxvj/)

My Code so far...

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
.accordion {
    margin: 50px;
    width:830px;
}
.accordion dd {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.accordion dt, .accordion dd {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.accordion dt:last-of-type, .accordion dd:last-of-type {

}
.accordion dt a, .accordion dd a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.accordion dd {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -15px;
    width:760px;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-top: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px 0px rgba(148,148,148,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px 0px rgba(148,148,148,1);
box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px 0px rgba(148,148,148,1);
}
.accordion dd:last-of-type {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}
.click {
    color: #8aca38;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<dl class="accordion">
  <dt><a href=""><img src="banner.jpg"></a></dt>
  <dd>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc. Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.<br>
  <br>
  <span class="click">Click for Details</span></dd>
  <dt><a href=""><img src="banner.jpg"></a></dt>
  <dd>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc. Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.<br>
  <br>
  <span class="click">Click for Details</span></dd>
  <dt><a href=""><img src="banner.jpg"></a></dt>
  <dd>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc. Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.<br>
  <br>
  <span class="click">Click for Details</span></dd>
</dl>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    var dt = $(this).parent().next();
      if(dt.data('visible') == true){
       dt.slideUp();   
       dt.data('visible',false);
      }
      else{
          dt.slideDown();
          dt.data('visible',true);
      }
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to set up a jsfiddle for us with absolute paths to your images. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I've never used jsfiddle before.. not sure if this works or not? http://jsfiddle.net/hf9ty8xe/

Comment: Just updated your fiddle you have to mention your framework and extension in terms of jquery to work. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hf9ty8xe/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add and remove class with css transitions to achieve this.

*NOTE: I had to change the html a little*

```
<dd><p>...</p>
  <span class="click">Click for Details</span></dd>
```

and the javascript

```
(function($) {

  //var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dd > .click').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    var dt = $(this).parent();
      if(dt.data('visible') == true){
         dt.removeClass('active');
           dt.data('visible',false);
      }
      else{

          dt.addClass('active'); 
          dt.data('visible',true);
      }
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4fa4j2o/1/)

The key is the CSS changes to set the height of the `<p>` to 0 and expand it when active

```
.accordion dd p {
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:1px;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s;
    transition: height 1s;
}

.accordion dd.active p {
    height:100px;
    margin:1px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much!! Is there a way to make the "Click here for details" change into "Close" so they know how to close the section that appears?